# live video streaming in android 1.6 gives error

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have this video streaming code in android2.2

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(URL);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

But it doesnt work on android 1.6 it gives the error

```
11-22 10:39:33.245: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info UNKNOWN PVMFStatus
11-22 10:39:33.245: ERROR/MediaPlayer(256): error (200, -32)
11-22 10:39:33.255: ERROR/MediaPlayer(256): Error (200,-32)
```

Comment: What is the protocol of the video streamed? Checkout http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html for supported formats and protocols.

Comment: I have the same problem. On some devices video plays well, on other it doesn't play at all.