# Android live video streaming not working in android1.6

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have the code of video streaming that works perfectly in android 2.2

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.start();
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
videoView.requestFocus();
```

But it doesn't work in andrid1.6 It gives the error:

```
11-22 11:12:51.455: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info UNKNOWN PVMFStatus
11-22 11:12:51.467: ERROR/MediaPlayer(826): error (200, -32)
11-22 11:12:51.467: ERROR/MediaPlayer(826): Error (200,-32)
11-22 11:12:51.467: DEBUG/VideoView(826): Error: 200,-32
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4242479/418183) question.